# Inline list in python reallocate memory?

Tags: python, for-loop, memory-management

I have a pairs of objects that I want to iterate over. Example:

```
contentA = [1, 2, ..... 100000]
lenA = 123.12

contentB = [1, 2, ..... 100000]
lenB = 123.12

contentC = [1, 2, ..... 100000]
lenC = 123.12
```

Now to iterate over them, I am using the following python syntax:

```
for (contType, contLen) in [(contentA, lenA), (contentB, lenB), (contentC, lenC)]:
  # Do something
```

This works just fine, but my question is:
**Does declaring a inline list in a for loop first allocates memory and then iterates over them?**

Since objects in question are huge and the number of iterations that I have to do this is also enormous, allocating memory again & again will consume memory as well as time.

Comment: That list only has three elements.

Comment: The memory allocation is trivial, since it *doesn't* copy the sublists. Even if `contentA` is huge, this will not create a copy of `contentA`.

Comment: @user2357112 ah, in that case I should be fine. Just to clarify, the contType object will then refer to content{A,B,C} ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The size of list is not my concern, the memory consumption & efficiency is what bothers me. Any better representation to reduce the memory footprint or code length is welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

The list you create to iterate over the elements contain only pointers on `ContentA`, `ContentB` and `ContentC`.

Since in that example there is only 3 element it will cost in you memory the size of a list of 3 tuple (float, pointer). Which is not so much.

If you want to be a little bit more efficient you can iterate over the tuple `((contentA, lenA), (contentB, lenB), (contentC, lenC))`.